# Show a message to the user instead of blank report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I couldn't find this anywhere.

Maybe you folks are able to put some light on this.

I am using Reporting Services 2008 R2 with ASP.NET 3.5 SP1.

What I need to accomplish is, in case of report has no data to show, do not show it (it shows empty). Instead, I want to show a message on the browser like "No data found".

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: @stubaker In fact, my question is a bit different. I don't want to show the message on the report, but on the browser. Thank you anyway.

Comment: There is no way to do that using the SSRS report manager. Your best option is what @stubaker said.